# Access property of object nested in array nested in object with a for loop Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nested, schema

I'm new to js (clearly). I'm using mongoose and I was wondering : why do I get an error while accessing property with a for loop?

I'm using a schema that contains embedded schema

```
Usr.findOne({numCli: req.body.numTar}, function(err, doc){

  if (doc) {

    var i = 0;
    const lengthAcc = doc.acc.length;
//can access prop individually
    console.log(doc.acc[lengthAcc-1].propOne);

// can't using for loop: TypeError: Cannot read property 'propOne' of undefined
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(doc.acc[lengthAcc - i].propOne);


    }
  }
 });
```

Comment: Why to 10? AFAIK Mongoose does not do negative notation on lengths

Comment: Should have clarifed. Each array has 10 objects in it. Just thought I could use a for loop to access each prop of each individual object

Comment: `i=1`, start `i` from `1`

Comment: I don't think you have 10 elements in what you are checking. `console.log(doc.acc[-1].propOne)` will reproduce the error. Instead your loop should be `for (i = 1; i < lengthAcc; i++)` to ensure you are not ever using a negative notation. Note these are not *"really"* arrays, but complex objects which just have *"array like accessors"*. Hence the difference.

Comment: Thanks. Should have seen it, yet it had eluded me for quite come time. Definitely need a break. And thanks for the clarification regarding those "arrays". Will look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If check your code then in first console

```
 console.log(doc.acc[lengthAcc-1].propOne);
```

you are try to access doc.acc[lengthAcc-1].propOne so it's work

but in second console

```
console.log(doc.acc[lengthAcc - i].propOne);
```

you are try to access doc.acc[lengthAcc-i].propOne and i=0 so it's doc.acc[lengthAcc-0].propOne that's why it's not work

bcz array.length return number of element in array,
so if array contain 5 element (0-4) so array.length return 5

and if you try to access array[array.length - 1] = 4 it's equal to array[4] so it's work

but if you try to access array[array.length - 0] = 5 it's equal to array[5] and array doe not have index 5 so it throw error.

So, the solution is just start for loop from 1

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
console.log(doc.acc[lengthAcc - i].propOne);
}
```